# Ionic 2 shared component

Tags: ionic-framework, menu, components, shared

I building an ionic 2 project and I want to share header and sidemenu between pages! some one can help please ? I have add the side menu to app.html file :

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)">
        Home
      </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(friendsPage)">
        Friends
      </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="openPage(eventsPage)">
        Events
      </button>
            <button ion-item (click)="closeMenu()">
        Close Menu
      </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: what are your exactions? what you want to share?

Comment: I want to share this menu with all page

Comment: It is already shared.

Comment: I've made a button in the profile page to show the menu , so I need to make a header or some thing like that will shared with all page, because it's not a good practice to defined every time the toggle button on all page? do you understand me ?

Comment: Do you want that button on all pages?

Comment: yes, may be define one header component contain that button and call it in all page ! if you have another suggestion please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to create shared component.

This will work for you, in efficient way.

page.ts

```
   <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>

        <button ion-button menuToggle>

          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>

        </button>

        <ion-title>About</ion-title>

        <ion-buttons end>

          <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">

            <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>

          </button>

        </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Refere official demo [conference app](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app)

Comment: I'm starting follow the ionic conference app structure . Can you please check this and give some help :                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314803/ionic-3-menu-sidebar

Answer (score 0):

This is not good idea to use but you can try this in your app.html
apart from menu

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-header>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```